# How to style a <div> rectangle with notched bottom with pure CSS?

Tags: css

I have a regular `<div>` element currently styled to look like a plain rectangle with rounded edges like this:

[image]

Is there a way to style it with just CSS (without adding any additional html elements to it) to make it look like this with a 'brace' on each end of the bar:

[image]

Here's a small cut out from my code of what I have at the moment:

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='rectangle'>&nbsp</div>
```

Comment: You can use `::before` and `::after` pseudo selectors to have the desired behavior.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3krmxsdc/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `border`:

```css
.brace {
  width: 400px; height:20px;
  background-color: grey;
  border:solid 10px;
  border-color: #0000 #0000 #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brace"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to play around a bit with the settings below to get the precise size/shape you need, but you can do it by using a pseudo element, similar to the snippet below.

The `:after` rule creates an additional element which overlaps the main element.

```css
.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.rectangle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 380px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class='rectangle'>&nbsp</div>
```